# Why is just one byte read but the file pointer moved by the correct amount in my example?

Tags: c

I've got a really strange problem.
If I use `fread` my file pointer is moved by the correct amount of bytes, but only one byte is read into the buffer.

Here's my file related code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdint.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>

#define READSIZE  1024
void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
 //main and other variable definitions
    unsigned char *buf;
    FILE *file;
    int filesize, read_bytes;

    buf=malloc(READSIZE+1);

    file=fopen(argv[1],"rb");

    fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_END);
    filesize = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_SET);
    while(read_bytes=fread(buf,1,READSIZE,file) == READSIZE)
    {
        printf("%d %d\n",read_bytes,ftell(file));
    }
    printf("%d %d\n",read_bytes,ftell(file));
}
```

And here's my output:

> 1 1024
>
> 1 2048
>
> 1 3072
>
> 1 4096
>
> 1 5120
>
> 1 6144
>
> 1 7168

I'm using the gcc compiler!

Comment: I've swapped your tag to C as you'll get a much better pool of answerers for this question.

Comment: Sorry, C is better, I took C++ accidentally!

Comment: No worries. The next thing people are going to ask about is an [mcve].

Comment: This is minimal, complete and verifyable, if you close the bracket! I could include the rest of my source code, but it's completely useless and would not be minimal! The only thing that's missing is `READSIZE`, but from the context you see that it has to be 1024...

Comment: Not really. No headers, and Crom only knows what happens inside the [...] segments. They may not be important, but what do we know? Save yourself the trouble and write up the MCVE. Include a sample file that exposes the error. The true beauty of the MCVE is quite often writing one exposes the error and eliminates the need for the question. My personal view is if you don't have something that approaches a MCVE you haven't done enough debugging yet.

Comment: The [...] segments are not related to the file pointer or the buffer and should have no side effects! But i'll add the header.

Comment: And that's why stuffing all that into the `while()` statement with `while(read_bytes=fread(buf,1,READSIZE,file) == READSIZE)` is a **horrible** coding style.  You've crammed an `fread()` call, an assignment, and a comparison all into one set of parenthesis and lost track of what actually is going on.  **Use more than one line.**  You're not trying to trim two pages and $0.03 off the cost of a two-hundred page textbook so the publisher can get a bigger swimming pool.

Answer (score 1):

```
while (read_bytes = fread(buf, 1, READSIZE, file) == READSIZE || ![...])
```

Ignoring the `[...]` for now, what is happening here is a problem with [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). In particular, `=` has lower precedence than `==`. So, this:

```
read_bytes = fread(buf, 1, READSIZE, file) == READSIZE
```

Is the same as:

```
read_bytes = (fread(buf, 1, READSIZE, file) == READSIZE)
```

Which basically says "set the value of `read_bytes` to 1 if `READSIZE` bytes were read, 0 otherwise." What you probably wanted was:

```
(read_bytes = fread(buf, 1, READSIZE, file)) == READSIZE
```

But I would discourage this because of the kind of bugs it can introduce, like what happened in your case.

And back to the `![...]`. `||` also has a higher precedence than `=` – however, in your code the `fread(...) == READSIZE` always evaluated to `true`, so the or-operator short-circuited and the other operand was never executed. Keep this in mind.

Comment: From what I understand from the code, OP's argument for `size` *is* 1.

Comment: What do you want to say with this? I've already read the documentation and my `size` argument is 1!

Comment: I've solved it myself before I saw your edit, but thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it.

The file was read correctly but I've forgot the brackets around `read_bytes=fread(buf,1,READSIZE,file)` and `==` binds stronger than `=`.

Comment: *but I've forgot the brackets* No, you forgot to use more than one line and avoid creating the bug in the first place.

Comment: What do you mean with this?

Comment: He means that if you had written `fread; while { printf; fread }` you would not have encountered this problem at all. While I get where Andrew's coming from, I'm not sure I'd go that way here. It's possible someone  could drop a side effect from a bug fix/added feature into only one of the `fread`s and have a much harder-to-spot bug.

Comment: Since you've already gotten `filesize` I would probably do something like  `while (filesize > 0) { read_bytes = fread(...); printf(...); filesize -= read_bytes; }`